# Importing gradle project from SVN on Eclipse [Updated: Gradle build error]

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am having trouble importing a project into Eclipse from SVN. This project works and builds on another computer, and I am trying to set it up on a new computer.
I am able to checkout the project into Eclipse from SVN like so:
[image]

The problem is Eclipse does not recognise it as a gradle project, even though the project folder contains a **.gradle** folder, a **build.gradle** file and a **.project** file.

The .project file appears to show it should be built by gradle and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Server</name>
    <comment>Project Server created by Buildship.</comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

However, clicking **Gradle | Refresh Gradle Project** does not download any of the project dependencies. Also, no available tasks are shown in the **Gradle Tasks** window.

I have read a workaround is to import the project to a local folder with an SVN client such as tortoiseSVN, and then in Eclipse import the local folder as a gradle project. But this means the project files would not reside in the Eclipse workspace folder.

If anyone knows of a "proper" way of importing a gradle project from SVN, I would be grateful for your advice.

Many thanks!

-------------------------------------

**[Update 5th Sept 2023]**

With advice provided by @Howlger and further investigation it appears that Eclipse has in fact recognised my project as a Gradle project.
The problem is when opening the **Gradle Tasks** view in Eclipse, no tasks are available and the Eclipse **Console** displays the error (showing only a snippet):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\project-files\eclipse-gb-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\project-files\eclipse-gb-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
```

This is likely an incompatibility between the Eclipse Gradle plugin and the version of JDK used for building the project. The default JRE is JDK 15.0.2 (AdoptOpenJDK).

[image]

The project uses the Gradle wrapper which is version 6.7.1

[image]

And according to the Gradle compatability matrix, Java 1.5 is the right version of JDK for Gradle 6.7

[image]

So it seems to be the correct JDK for the version of Gradle.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: According to the `.project` file, it was recognized as a Gradle project, which can also be seen by the project folder being decorated with a small Gradle elephant. Gradle is very picky about which Java version it runs with. Please tell which Eclipse and Buildship versions do you have and with which Java version you run Eclipse and which Java version do you use in your project. Anything in the error log? If yes, please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Thank you for your help @howlger. On further investigation, I see Eclipse has in fact shown an error in the console when trying to generate the "Gradle Tasks". I shall update my question. Cheers!

Comment: According to the screenshot you Eclipse is outdated. First, please make sure that your Eclipse IDE is up to date to have the latest fixes and improving for Gradle. Please also show your build.gradle.

Comment: The Eclipse installation is the latest one at the time (2023-06).  I have managed to get Gradle working in Eclipse now and will add the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get my Gradle project working on Eclipse (2023-06) in the end and wanted to share it.

Even though I had already set the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable on my machine (Windows 11) to point to JDK 15 and the default Eclipse JRE to JDK 15, it can be seen that the Gradle wrapper was still trying to use JDK 17.

**Solution:**
I set **Java home** of the Gradle preferences in Eclipse to also point to JDK 15, like so:

[image]

Once I did that, Gradle starting working and downloading my dependancies.

I did not need to do this on a previous (older) installation of Eclipse, so perhaps something has changed in this version.

Hopefully anyone facing a similar issue will find this helpful.